# compare TreeMap key and value in Java

Tags: java, comparison, treemap

I have two TreeMap Like this: 
treemapOne:

```
{AUF_1413716534902_74=[Aufgabe, Function 1],
AUF_1413755000138_37=[Aufgabe, Function 2], 
AUF_1414931037395_41=[Aufgabe, Function 5],
AUF_1415377008757_59=[Aufgabe, Function 4], 
AUF_1415782696600_1801=[Aufgabe, Function 3_Eltern], 
AUF_1424125084448_1869=[Aufgabe, FunctionAlone]}
```

and 
treemaptwo:

```
 {AUF_1415377008757_59=[AUF_1414931037395_41], 
AUF_1415782696600_1801=[AUF_1413755000138_37, AUF_1413716534902_74]}
```

i want to get key(s) from treemapone which are not in elements (key or value) of treemaptwo, which means here  AUF_1424125084448_1869. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both maps are instances of `Map<String, List<String>>`, you can do:

```
// init result set with keys from treemapOne
Set<String> remainingKeys = new HashSet<>(treemapOne.keySet());
// remove keys in treemapTwo
remainingKeys.removeAll(treemapTwo.keySet());
// remove values in treemapTwo
for (List<String> values : treemapTwo.valueSet()) {
    remainingKeys.removeAll(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the simple and obvious way:

```
for (String key : treemapOne.keys()) {
    if (!treemapTwo.containsKey(key)) {
        // key is in the first map but not the second, do something about that
    }
}
```

Comment: @tbodt surely that first edit is too minor, and that second one is a change of the author's intent? (I'm not really clear on the editing guidelines though)

Comment: the first one was a little reformatting, so maybe it was too minor. the second one because the OP will cut and paste your code without realizing there's a `System.out.println` in the middle of it.

Comment: @tbodt because the OP will copy 5 lines of code without reading them? by that logic the OP will copy your code without realizing there's a comment in the middle of it

Comment: thanks, but this would not compare keys of treemapone with values of treemaptwo. That is what i have to do, because may be there is a key which is not in keys of treemaptwo but in its values and i want to check that.